# Installed ImageMagick7-7.0.1.5 on FreeBSD 10.3 but there is no `import` command available after installation

Tags: freebsd, imagemagick, bsd

After running `$ sudo pkg install ImageMagick7-7.0.1.5` on FreeBSD 10.3, noticed that what I needed is not installed: `import`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need to, but run `sudo pkg install ImageMagick7-7.0.1.5` again.

I've just tried it on my machine and the first time it only appears to install dependencies, the second time it installs ImageMagick and the expected commands.

Update 25/06/16:
This appeared to be due to a bug in `pkg`(1), and has now been [fixed according to this bug report.](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=210370)

Comment: I've opened a bug on “graphics/ImageMagick7”: https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=210370

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `import` an imagemagick 6 legacy command line tool? ImageMagick does everything through the `magick` command. The ImageMagick 7 windows installer just offered to install legacy command line tools, I guess they are available as a separate package for FreeBSD & Linux?